# Configuring proftpd and mod_ldap.c query not working - any ideas?

Tags: ftp, ldap, proftpd

I'm trying to get a ProFTPD to LDAP auth on a Active Directory base. I still couldn't figure out what could be wrong with my configuration since, executing a LDAP query with `ldapsearch` seems fine

## proftpd.conf

```
/etc/proftpd.conf

# This is the ProFTPD configuration file
ServerName                      "FTP and Ldap"
ServerType                      standalone
ServerAdmin                     nicolas@domain.com.br
AuthOrder                       mod_ldap.c
LoadModule                      mod_ldap.c
DefaultServer                   on
ShowSymlinks                    on
RootLogin                       off
UseIPv6                         off
AllowLogSymlinks                on
IdentLookups                    off
UseReverseDNS                   off
Umask                           077
User                            ftp
Group                           ftp
DefaultRoot                     /home/ftp/%u/
DefaultChDir                    ftp
RequireValidShell               off
UseFtpUsers                     off
SystemLog                       /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
TransferLog                     /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
DefaultTransferMode             binary

<IfModule mod_ldap.c>
        LDAPServer                      domaincontroller.domain.net
        LDAPAttr                        uid sAMAccountName
        LDAPDNInfo                      cn=linux.ldap,ou=users,ou=resources,dc=domain,dc=net password
        LDAPAuthBinds                   on
        LDAPDoAuth                      on "dc=domain,dc=net" (&(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectclass=User))
        LDAPQueryTimeout                15

        LDAPGenerateHomedir             on
        LDAPGenerateHomedirPrefix       /home/ftp

        #uid e guid of the local global user
        LDAPDefaultUID                  14
        LDAPDefaultGID                  50
        LDAPForceDefaultUID             on
        LDAPForceDefaultGID             on
</IfModule>

<Directory /*>
        AllowOverwrite                  on
</Directory>
```

## proftpd -nd10 -> "search failed"

Running proftpd with a debug level of 10 I got these logs while authenticating with my user (`nicolas`):

```
proftpd -nd10


dispatching CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
mod_ldap/2.8.22: generated filter dc=domain,dc=net from template dc=domain,dc=net and value nicolas
mod_ldap/2.8.22: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=nicolas)(objectclass=User)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectclass=User)) and value nicolas
mod_ldap/2.8.22: attempting connection to ldap://domaincontroller.domain.net/
mod_ldap/2.8.22: set protocol version to 3
mod_ldap/2.8.22: connected to ldap://domaincontroller.domain.net/
mod_ldap/2.8.22: successfully bound as cn=linux.ldap,ou=users,ou=resources,dc=domain,dc=net password
mod_ldap/2.8.22: set dereferencing to 0
mod_ldap/2.8.22: set query timeout to 15s
mod_ldap/2.8.22: pr_ldap_search(): LDAP search failed: Operations error
```

## ldapsearch works

But `ldapsearch` on the other hand works just fine:

```
[root@ftp2 ~]# ldapsearch -x -W -D "cn=linux.ldap,ou=users,ou=resources,dc=domain,dc=net" -h domaincontroller.domain.net -b "dc=domain,dc=net" -LLL "(SAMAccountName=nicolas)"
Enter LDAP Password: 

dn: CN=Nicolas XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Nicolas XXXXXXX
sn: XXXXXXX
description:XXXXXXX
givenName: XXXXXXX
distinguishedName:
```

Any clues?

Comment: outdated, but ...... you've been configure (sAMAccountName=%v) , but it should be (sAMAccountName=%u)  .  mistake in configuration variable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, the URL must be [RFC 2255](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2255) compliant and, using Proftpd queries will only work when they are filtered by an OU. These queries will not work at LDAP root level.

```
LDAPServer ldap://domaincontroller.domain.net:389/??sub
```

Organizational Unity:

```
LDAPDoAuth on "OU=OFFICE,dc=domain,dc=net" (&(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectclass=User))
```

Umask inside the dir. The limits are just for safety

```
<Directory />
Umask 022 022
AllowOverwrite on
        <Limit MKD XMKD CDUP XCUP CWD XCWD RMD XRMD>
        DenyAll
        </Limit>
</Directory>
```